# POST to Web API OData, the entity that is received is null

Tags: jquery, post, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm trying to send data to Web API using OData. But the entity which is received is always null.

I have this call using JQuery:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "/odata/Products",
            type: "POST",
            //contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(productToAdd),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                alert("Server call has been OK!!");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Server call has been failed!!");
            }
        });
```

The productToAdd object is like:

{"name":"Apple","description":"Good!!","price":"12.3","category":"Fruit"}

My controller is:

```
public class ProductsController : EntitySetController<Product, string>
{
    private IProductService _prodSvc;

    public ProductsController(IProductService prodSvc)
    {
        _prodSvc = prodSvc;
    }

    [Queryable]
    public override IQueryable<Product> Get()
    {
        return _prodSvc.GetAllProducts();
    }

    protected override Product CreateEntity(Product product)
    {
       var addedProduct = _prodSvc.AddProduct(product);
       return addedProduct;
    }
}
```

Also I've tried to use the datajs-1.10.js framework but I have got the same result.

```
        OData.request(
          {
              requestUri: "/odata/Products",
              method: "POST",
              data: productToAdd
          },
          function (data) {
              alert("Server call has been OK!!");
          }
        );
```

I think that something is wrong when it deserializes the JSON object but I don't know what. Could you help me?

Thanks!!

Comment: In general, I recommend trying to first figure out if the issue is a client-side one or a server-side one when you run into problems like this. Take a look at what is being returned from the server with a tool like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) (or anything else that will monitor your HTTP requests and responses). Is the server sending back a successful status code or an error?

Comment: Can you check the ModelState property on your controller? That should have any information about deserialization failures.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the model binder for web api for some reason isn't behaving in the way that we have come to expect from model binding in mvc, however the context is slightly different here, a form post is not quite the same as a JSON object payload ...

For example: 
If I define the following class in C# ...

```
class Foo 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

... then given a method signature of ...

```
public void SomeMethod(Foo data) { ... }
```

... In MVC I could post any arbritrary lump of data and anything that matched at least some of the properties would get bound.
This happens to with Web API but only if you post a content type of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and I stringify my data.

If you however want to post proper JSON you have to be explicit and correct and if you supply 1 less property or an extra property it'll fail with a modelstate validation error which is very obscure and just says something like "posted data failed validation", not helpful.

You should be able to see this by putting a breakpoint on the first line of your controller then examining that values in Modelstate.
No exception, just validation fails and null params.

The data however should still be there and nothing stops you manually parsing it from the request stream yourself with the 2 or 3 lines of code it would take.
I'm going to suggest in this instance that you confirm your json exactly matches your DTO.

Given that this is the case then this should work ...

```
$.ajax({
    type: method,
    url: url,
    data: someObject,
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;odata=minimalmetadata");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=minimalmetadata");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        // add say auth headers here for secure endpoints
    },
    success: function (newObj) {
        // job done
    },
    error: function (e) {
        // nope, examine what server said
    }
});
```